# How does the Linear class in torch.nn work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, oop

```
class LR(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = Linear(input_size, output_size)
  def forward(self, x):
    pred = self.linear(x)
    return pred
```

In the above code, the 'forward' method has the parameter x. In the method, 'pred' is assigned 'self.linear(x)'. So what is this x being passed to, as self.linear does not take any arguments.

Comment: How do you expect someone to answer this? Please see [mcve]

Comment: this could work if `Linear` is a (badly named) function that returns a function that takes one parameter - OR if Linear() is creating a class with al `__call__` dunder. Neither makes sense with the amount of info you provide - why tag all this useless tags and not provide the imports and frameworks pertaining to the code you show?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

X is the representative of the x-axis, which is the variable that tells the program to go which side. I think it is a program belonging to "the mobile animation direction program".

Answer (score 1):

u can refer to this official document [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html). notice that `m` is called with the random array `input`.